# Performance gain by using bulk inserts vs regular inserts in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, performance, pymongo, database

What is the performance gain by using bulk inserts vs regular inserts in MongoDB and pymongo specifically. Are bulk inserts just a wrapper for regular inserts?

Comment: to gain performance for mass inserts, try to use mongoimport (you need to create appropriate json or csv file). it may be x10 faster than bulk insert, however mongoimport is very slow for upserts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bulk inserts are no wrappers for regular inserts. A bulk insert operation contains many documents sent as a whole. It saves as many database round trips. It is much more performant since you don't have to send each document over the network separately.

Comment: however, on the server they are still inserted individually.

Comment: ... and you also loose the ability to easily tell which documents failed to be inserted and which succeeded from a batch. This is an area where asynchronous drivers start to show big benefits.

Comment: The feature to report error for any individual insert (in a bulkinsert operation) added in mongodb 2.6

Answer (score -1):

@dsmilkov Thats an advantage as you dont have to open a connection every single time.