# Mongodb bulkWrite executing in parallel?

Tags: mongodb-java

In [mongodb documentation](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/bulk-write-operations/) with regards to  "Unordered Bulk Write" we have *"With an unordered list of operations, MongoDB can execute the operations in parallel, but this behavior is not guaranteed."*

Using the java driver (v 3.2.0) it looks like

```
collection.bulkWrite(documents, new BulkWriteOptions().ordered(false) )
```

is not executed in parallel. What can trigger a parallel execution of `bulkWrite` ?

Comment: Were you able to figure this out?

Comment: The doco says "can" by I doubt that it currently does. At least not when driven via Java. You can get major throughput increases by running in parallel on the application side.

Comment: Without trying too hard I get x6 throughput by running `bulkWrite` concurrently: https://github.com/sorokod/mongoinserts/

Comment: Thanks for replying. I was going through some links like and looks the only  benefit with bulkWrite on the client side saving on the roundtrips. In bulkWrite only 1 request (with the different operations grouped) is sent to the database. I'm not sure what happens on the db side, with unordered bulkWrites. Like you've said the doc says MongoDb "can" execute in parallel. But looking at some posts like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16533420/performance-gain-by-using-bulk-inserts-vs-regular-inserts-in-mongodb it's sequential on the server side.